# MySQL - Efficient Date Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to optimize some queries that involve comparing dates. This is done in PHP. Currently the setup for the WHERE statements looks like:

```
WHERE
search_deals_online.expirationDate > DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -1 DAY ) AND 
search_deals_online.createDate > DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -30 DAY )
```

However, this seems like it would have to calculate the date at every row (~250k). Would it be worth hardcoding the date via PHP so it would look like:

```
WHERE
search_deals_online.expirationDate > '2014-11-12' AND 
search_deals_online.createDate > '2014-10-13'
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about such calculations on constants.  They should be evaluated during the compile stage of the query (although I cannot guarantee that MySQL does that, most databases do).

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you need to do this query often, then you should consider an index covering the date columns in question.  Also, make sure you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table or a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` field which should help indexing.

Then, just make sure that one side of each expression is a field name.  For example, always use `search_deals_online.expirationDate > DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL -1 DAY )` over `DATEDIFF(search_deals_online.expirationDate, CURDATE()) > 1`.  A field inside a function is not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and will not take advantage of your indexes.